# Filtered View gives duplicates

Tags: views

I'm creating a View that creates a page based on filters.

Filters are:

- Published AND
- Content: Type (= Student Resources) AND
- Content: Resources Tag (Both or Prospective)

In the end, this should retrieve `"Student Resources"` that are `Published` and that have been tagged as either `"Prospective"` or `"Both"`.  It does this without problem.  However, what it also does is show the output multiple times:

[image: Image of site]

Only one of each of these content exist, but each is showing up 6 times.

Please help me troubleshoot.  What other information can I give you?

Comment: Which format setting are you using under views UI? Grid?

Comment: Yes, Format: Grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by installing the [Views Distinct Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_distinct).

Once installed, I added `Content: Resources Tag (Both or Prospective)` to my fields in the view of interest.  Then clicked on that field and under `Views Distinct Settings`, chose `Filter Repeats`.

I got this from this video: [How To Remove Views Duplicates (Drupal Tutorial)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sO2cpPjxr4c)

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this article [Remove Duplicate Views Results](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/duplicate-views-results/). Yo can use second option from that article.

Generally, it is done by the `Enabling Aggregation: Yes` under Views UI. This all has been mentioned at that link. Hope it will help.

Comment: I tried this (Aggregation, yes; count-distinct=1), and all results then disappear as soon as I turn Aggregation on.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solutions in this article don't work : [Remove Duplicate Views Results](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/duplicate-views-results/).

The duplicate was due to an image field. I found this solution : set `Exclude from display` for the fields and set `REWRITE RESULTS / Override the output of this field` with custom text and use the token for the field `{{ field_my_image }}`

I don’t know exactly why it has solved the issue but there is no more duplicate.