# How to avoid showing duplicate content in Views?

Tags: 7, views

I have a View block that displays all of the nodes written by an author on their profile. However, I'm having trouble with Views spitting out duplicate content.

For styling and functionality purposes, all of the fields are being outputted through an extra title field. I simply rewrote the output of the added title field, including tokens for all of my fields. I then set all of the fields (except for the rewritten title field) to "Display None", so that the fields were not duplicated.

Below is a screenshot of my current Views setup.

> [image]

Here is a screenshot of the Views grid on the user profile. Ignore the missing images. I don't have all of the websites images synced to my local environment.

> [image]

I tried using the "Distinct" option in the query settings, which eliminated most of the duplicates. However, Views continues to duplicate random content. Some content will have no duplicates, some content has multiple duplicates.

I've also tried using aggregation, but Views will not output anything when I turn aggregation on. I'd love for aggregation to be the solution, but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using @CodeNext's advice, I rebuilt my view while monitoring the output on the user profile page. I discovered that the `File: Name` field was causing the duplicates. It never crossed my mind that it would have caused the duplicates. I was using that field to generate a image path for the Pinterest button. To avoid using this field, I downloaded the [Image URL Formatter module](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter). It was easy to generate an image path by adding another image field and selecting the URL formatter option.

Comment: Glad you solved the issue..

Answer (score 3):

I have came across this question in past looks like it is same as your Question: [Filtered View gives duplicates](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/209368/filtered-view-gives-duplicates/209371#209371)

Referring that, I came to know you can use [Views Distinct](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_distinct).

And you can follow this video tutorial: [How To Remove Views Duplicates (Drupal Tutorial)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sO2cpPjxr4c).

Comment: Using Views Distinct, I selected the `Filter Repeats` option for the `Taxonomy term: Name` field. It seemed to remove the duplicates, but now the number of items displayed on each page varies. For example, the first page is supposed to display 12, but with Views Distinct applied, it only displays 3 items.

Comment: @KellenLester Hey Kellen, I did not find the time to reply your comment, sorry for that, But I will reply after study that in some time. Thanks for patience.

Comment: No problem. Just to give an update, I've tried eliminating relationships to see if I could narrow down the problem causer. I removed both of the author relationships, but the duplicates remained. I also tried removing the taxonomy relationship which did not solve the problem either.

Comment: I have one question, As per your views setting, you are using `Format: Unformatted list`, then how are getting the Grid view(12 items)?  Are you doing this using CSS?

Comment: The number of items outputted (per page) is dictated with the Pager settings. The actual grid design was created with CSS.

Comment: Are you getting the duplication of certain numbers like I can see from image it looks maximum three, Or it is just random?

Comment: I guess this issue can be solved by try & error only. I would like to give you one suggestion, if you can try. Create a fresh other block, add each components one by one (i.e. each field, each relationship, each filter etc), not all at a time, each things one by one. And after every change check the views, at one point your views will start Duplicating, hence you will come to know which component you added last and mostly that one will be the culprit. This will save your time. Other thing, your views shows three `Content: title`, I guess that are contributing, probably three dulpicates..;).

Comment: Interesting theory. I don't know how I can get around not using the three title fields. The first two are formatted differently. One outputs a linked title, and the other outputs a plain text title which is used in the share buttons html code. The last title field is simply being used to rewrite the content as stated in my initial post. I would have used the body field, but it doesn't exist on all of the node types. Anyway, thanks for the advice! I'll try reconstructing the view to see if I can determine the problem.

Comment: Ah..might be it is not `content:` then...Generally I like to solve the issue of views by creating same view at my trial site and then do try and error, but your views seems very complex, if I try also I can't as I do not know what setting each component has, so I can guess only. Why I suggest you to go by this way, It may precisely point out the issue...Hope you find the solution. If you like you can send me the screen-shot of your content type setting page, and Views page in chat, so I will try to reconstruct.

Comment: @CodeNext Views Distinct module worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I see you have 2 content author relationships. You should only need 1 of them. Remove the 1st one, highlighted in blue in your pic.

Now click on `user: content authored`, make sure you have checkmarked ☑ require relationship.

Comment: I was able to remove `user: content authored`, when I tried to remove `content: author`, my changes wouldn't save. I think that is because `user: content authored` is dependent on `content: author`. Regardless, using only `content: author` and selecting require relationship has not solved the problem.

Comment: @KellenLester try this, use `Content: Author uid` as relationship, and for contextual filter use `Content: Author uid`

Comment: `Content: Author uid` is not available as a relationship. Looks like `Content: Author` is the only option that would work.

Comment: @KellenLester Ooops sorry, I meant to say **`Content: Author` for relationship** and for **contextual filter `Content: Author uid`**

Comment: Ah... Yes, that's what I tried. It doesn't seem to change anything. Same issue is happening. Whatever the issue is, it definitely seems to be linked with the author. I though it may have been the taxonomy relationship. I tried removing it, but it had no effect.